# `devtools::load_all()` keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: r, keyboard, shortcut

I reinstalled the latest versions of R and R Studio, restarted my PC and downloaded all the packages I need – **devtools** is one of them. However, the keyboard short `Ctrl+Shift+L` stopped working.

If I manually type out `devtools::load_all()` in the console, it still works. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check in RStudio under Tools...Modify Keyboard Shortcuts. Search for "Execute devtools::load_all()" and make sure the shortcut is set.

Comment: Hi Flick,thanks yes I can very well see it.thats why am even more perplexed as to why I am not able to get it to work

Comment: Have you installed or updated any other software recently? It’s possible some other program has taken over global responsibility for that shortcut. I’m not sure which is version you are using but try searching for ways to see which programs respond to which shortcuts.

Comment: No not that I can think of..only R Studio

Comment: I have the same problem. I just updated R. Cmd+Shift+L no longer does load_all(), but Cmd+Shift+D is still doing documentation. This is driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy.

I solved it by:

- Open *"Tools -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts..."* from RStudio top menu
- Find *"Execute devtools::load_all()"* line and left click on it
- Click *"Reload"* from the menu as indicated in the figure below [image: Select reload option from]

No idea why, but it solved my problem. Now I can use the keyboard short `ctrl+shift+L`to run `devtools::load_all()`.

It would be interesting to have some clarifications about that.

Comment: Did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work, because devtools isn't installed!